# Prove that $OP^2=PC^2+OB^2$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose you have A,B,C,D four points in harmonic range and O, P are the midpoints of AB and CD respectively. Prove that $OP^2=PC^2+OB^2$.

I would guess that this is a sort of corollary to the theorem that says:

If $(ACBD)$ is a harmonic range and if $O$ is the midpoint of $AB$ then $OB^2=OC\cdot OD.$

But I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $F$ on the circle with diameter $AB$ be such that $FC$ is the angle bisector of $\angle AFB$. Since $(ACBD)$ is a harmonic range, $FD$ is the exterior angle bisector at $F$ of $\triangle AFB$. Consequently $\angle AFD=135^\circ$ and $FC\perp FD$.

It follows that $\angle OAF+\angle PDF=45^\circ.$ Hence $$\angle FOP+\angle FPO=90^\circ,$$
and we have 
$$OP^2=OF^2+PF^2=OB^2+PC^2.$$