# If $A, B, P$, and $Q$ are four harmonic points and $O$ and $M$ are the midpoints of $AB$ and $PQ$ respectively, then $(OB)^2 + (OP)^2 = (OM)^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I already computed that $OB^2 = (OP)(OQ)$ and $MP^2 = (MA)(MB)$, I tried to sum both equations but I can't get the result.

Here is the same question in another post: [Prove that $OP^2=PC^2+OB^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805932/prove-that-op2-pc2ob2) but I want to see if it's possible to show it with the equations that I got.

Comment: Perhaps you want to prove $(OB)^2 + (MP)^2 = (OM)^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct formula is $(OB)^2 + (MP)^2 = (OM)^2$?

Set a coordinate system on a line: $O(0)$, $A(2a)$, $B(-2a)$, $P(2p)$ and $Q(2q)$. Then $M(p+q)$. Now you have to prove $$4a^2+(p-q)^2=(p+q)^2 $$
which is the same as $a^2=pq$.
Now, since 
$${AP\over PB}:{AQ\over QB}=-1$$
we get $${a-p\over a+p}={q-a\over a+q}\implies a^2=pq$$
and we are done.